# May someone risk danger and harm to convert?

Tags: halacha-theory, conversion-to-judaism, danger

Historically there have been times where converting to Judaism was a crime punishable by the local rulers. The severity of the punishment in some instances was as extreme as being put to death.
I would like to know if there is any halachic literature discussing whether or not a person is allowed to convert in situations of great personal risk (bodily harm, monetary or otherwise).

Furthermore I would like to understand if the rabbinic authorities who perform conversions are allowed/prohibited to do so in instances of great personal risk to the convert.
In other words, even if a convert is allowed to proceed in situations of risk, perhaps those parties who would 'perform' the conversion are prohibited from doing so.

Comment: Beis Milah as an adult carries a certain amount of risk

Comment: @JoelK iinm poskim discuss a goy shemeitu achiv machmat milah

Comment: The vilna gaon spoke very highly about Avraham ben Avraham even though he ended up getting executed and he knew the risks from the outset